# cakePHP: sporadic occurrence of "Call to a member function allow() on a non-object"

Tags: php, cakephp

when I call a specifical controller-script of my Web-Application I sporadically get the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function allow() on a non-object in /srv/www/vhost/app/Controller/myController.php on line 11`

Line 11 contains
`$this->Auth->allow(array('get'));`

Anyone an idea what this may cause?

Regards,
~MxAgent

Comment: Make sure you have added the Auth component in your controller, `var $components = array('Auth');`

Comment: Yes I did. And the error occurs just every third call of the controller.. very misterious!

Comment: Is this in your beforeFilter()?

Comment: yep that's the beforeFilter()-Method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. It was a caching-problem due to server doesn't support APC.